# Conditional import to switch implementations

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have node.js application written in TypeScript and I need to switch between two interface implementations based on the config file. Currently I have this code which seems to be working.

```
"use strict";

import { config } from "../config";

let Something;
if (config.useFakeSomething) {
    Something = require("./FakeSomething").FakeSomething;
} else {
    Something = require("./RealSomething").RealSomething;
}
...
let s = new Something();
s.DoStuff();
...
```

But I have bad gut feeling about that (mainly because of the mixing **require** and **import** for loading modules). Is there some other way how to achieve implementation switching based on config file without importing both modules?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to keep the client-code for your `Something` class clean, you can move the conditional importing to a single file. You can have the following directory structure for your Something module:

```
/Something
    RealSomething.ts
    FakeSomething.ts
    index.ts
```

And in your index.ts, you can have the following:

```
import { config } from '../config';

const Something = config.useFakeSomething ?
    require('./FakeSomething').FakeSomething :
    require('./RealSomething').RealSomething;

export default Something;
```

And in your client code, you can just import `Something`:

```
import Something from './Something/index';
```

Comment: But this will load both modules always, won't it? I can't load RealSomething module on dev environment because it is initializing special hardware which is not there.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I'll update my answer. I don't think there's anything wrong using require within a TypeScript module to support this dynamic behavior. The issue would arise if you ever switch to a different module loader, but that should be infrequent.

Comment: The Fundamental Theorem of Computer Science provides the solution yet again. Love it!

Answer (score 6):

I can see nothing wrong with your approach. In fact lines like

```
import { config } from "../config";
```

When targeting commonjs will be compiled to the following javascript (ES6):

```
const config = require('../config');
```

So they are effectively identical and you are not mixing different module loading techniques.

Answer (score 6):

A modern answer using the **import()** function:

```
import { config } from "../config";

let Something;
if (config.useFakeSomething) {
    Something = (await import("./FakeSomething")).FakeSomething;
} else {
    Something = (await import("./RealSomething")).RealSomething;
}
...
let s = new Something();
s.DoStuff();
...
```

Remember that import() is non blocking, so you need to add **await** if the code that follows needs the result from the import().

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
let moduleLoader:any;

if( pladform == 1 ) {
    moduleLoader = require('./module1');
} else {
    moduleLoader = require('./module2');
}
```

and then

```
if( pladform === 1 ) {
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(moduleLoader.module1, [ languageService ]);
}
else if ( pladform === 2 ) {
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(moduleLoader.module2, [ languageService ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the correct answers above, in case you need this switching for many files within a single folder, you can use a symbolic-link (not available on Windows) that referenced to the right folder, so your code remains clean.

This approach is good for switching between real code and stubs, for instance