# angular-cli: Conditional Imports using an environment variable

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

Is there a way to conditionally change imports based on an environment variable in angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.16? I'm trying to do it in a way that doesn't require code changes in how services are imported in client code, but when needed I can specify a build flag to swap in mock services.

There is a pattern I tried using from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919878/conditional-import-to-switch-implementations):

> *File structure:*
>
> ```
> MyService
>     MyServiceMock.ts
>     MyServiceReal.ts
>     index.ts
> ```
>
> *And in your index.ts, you can have the following:*
>
> ```
> import { environment} from '../environments/environment';
>
> export const MyService = environment.mock ?
>     require('./MyServiceMock').MyServiceMock:
>     require('./MyServiceReal').MyServiceReal;
> ```
>
> *And in your client code, import MyService:*
>
> ```
> import MyService from './myservice/index';
> ```

The page loads, and I can see the dependency getting injected when stepping through the code, however there are compilation errors (which I believe are TypeScript errors) along the lines of `Cannot find name 'MyService'`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're going about it completely wrong. Angular can handle this use case with the use of *factories* when you configure the `providers`

```
providers: [
  Any,
  Dependencies
  {
    provide: MyService, 
    useFactory: (any: Any, dependencies: Dependencies) => {
      if (environment.production) {
        return new MyService(any, dependencies);
      } else {
        return new MockMyService(any, dependencies);
      }
    },
    deps: [ Any, Dependencies ]
]
```

Now you can just inject `MyService` everywhere because of the `provide: MyService`, but in development, you will get the mock, and in production you will get the real service.

**See Also:**

- [How to inject different service based on certain build environment in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39942256/2587435)

Comment: This approach works well, but has a drawback, that mock services are included into production package

Comment: How exactly do I inject the provider when it's created this way? Normally I would import from the file the service lives in, but in this case it could one of two files. How do I tell Angular I want the provider from the provided factory function?

Comment: @Valevalorin by the token (the `provide`), which is `MyService`. That's what you inject.

Comment: I need to know specifically what the line beginning with `import` looks like.

Comment: @Enargit list the mock and the real service in a module and then conditionally load that module in the imports section.
Also look at, where I got this answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51772549/2733437

Answer (score 0):

Change your MyService import to:

`import { MyService } from './myservice/index'`;

The surrounding `{}` will tell the compiler to import a single export from the file. If you want to be able to import like:

`import MyService from './myservice/index';`

Then you must have a default export in `index.ts` e.g:

`export default MyService;` .

More information on TypeScript modules can be found here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I am still running into the same error though, with `Cannot find name 'MyService'`. Also potentially of note: the static analysis of the typescript in VS Code echos the same error, indicating that the import is resolving, but when attempting to do dependency injection in the constructor it is not resolving the name.