# How to conditionally import library in angular depending on browser platform

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I need to import a library dynamically depending on the browser platform. To prevent Angular Universal from giving errors because its using the window object.

```
import * as Muuri from 'muuri';
```

So what I want is something like this:

```
if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platform)) {
     import * as Muuri from 'muuri';
    }
    else {
  declare var Muuri;
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work.

Comment: Check out this https://netbasal.com/using-typescript-dynamic-imports-in-angular-d210547484dd

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular universal: dynamic imports for browser only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751383/angular-universal-dynamic-imports-for-browser-only)

Comment: @ArunKumar I am not sure how to implement it:     if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platform)) {
      const moduleSpecifier = '* as Muuri from "muuri"';
      import(moduleSpecifier).then(module => {
        Muuri = module;
      });
    }?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
exportToExcel() {
    import("xlsx").then(xlsx => {
      // JUST USE THE LIBRARY
    });
  }
```

Comment: can you share it here

Comment: I used this: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/getting-started/angular-universal/ to solve window is not defined issue.

Answer (score 1):

try this code.

```js
    if (!isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
      const Muuri = (await import('muuri')).default;
      // or const Muuri = (await import('muuri'));
    }
```

Comment: This works and should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score -1):

No, unfortunately you can't conditionally import libraries. What you can do though is import both libraries, inject both in your constructor and then conditionally using `isDevMode()`, (there exists no isDebugMode()) you can use whatever you prefer for each case.

This is not a very good solution though, as it means you will load both libs in memory and since you inject them in the constructor the treeshaking that happens at build time will not ommit them.

If this is done sparingly it might even not make a difference though (negatively). I suggest you benchmark Memory size at runtime using dev tools and if there is significant gain to outweigh the manual nature of the cleaner approach, then just replace the Mock class in the import when you are done developing the feature using that Mock

Comment: But if I do this it still will result in "ReferenceError: window is not defined" this error right? Is there really no way to make this work?

Comment: Universal toolkit renders code on the Server Side and window object is only available in browsers that is why you are getting this error.

You can add condition to execute client side code only on browser by using isPlatformBrowser module .

Comment: I know that. But I need to conditionally import a library. Thats the question I asked.

Comment: You can do `const externalLib = await import('external-lib')` or in this case `const muuri = (await import('muuri')).default`. I dont see why you said we cant conditionally import libraries?