# Conditional import/export when using different environment

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, node-modules

I'm currently developing a Lambda function using node14 on AWS, but I have an issue when I want to develop it locally.

In my dev environment I have a corporate proxy needed to connect to AWS. In this case, I use `aws-sdk-proxy` library. However, I don't want to use this package while in production (as Lambda already has the `aws-sdk` injected in lambda core).

So, I created this snippet to perform the switch between the 2 environments:

```js
// aws.js
import AWSPROD from 'aws-sdk'
import AWSDEV from 'aws-sdk-proxy'
import config from '../lib/Config.js'
import logger from './logger.js'

let AWS = null

if (config.get('ENVIRONMENT') === 'dev') {
  logger.debug('[DEV] Using aws-sdk-proxy')
  AWS = AWSDEV
} else {
  AWS = AWSPROD
}

export default AWS
```

Not so clean, but it works. With this code, I can perform this:

```js
import AWS from './aws.js'
```

Now the problem is that this code implies that I must provide `aws-sdk-proxy` into the "prod" dependencies of my package.json.

I think it breaks performance of the lambda as the code raised 9Mo (2Mo without), but I wish to keep this way of calling "AWS" SDK [the 2d code block].

I tried to use `required` or dynamic `import` but none of these solutions work.

Do you have any advice to improve my code?

PS:

- The code is transpiled to ES5 using Babel to fit Lambda requirements
- `aws-sdk-proxy` library must stay in devDependencies as it's a dev dependency

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Conditional import to switch implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919878/conditional-import-to-switch-implementations).  This other post suggests you can use `require()` for conditional import in TypeScript.  And, dynamic imports using `import()` described [here](https://mitya.uk/articles/javascript-modules-conditional-import).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In fact, for your first suggestion, I don't know how I can mix Typescript and ES* code (.js), should I "compile" it to ES6 before using ? For your second suggestion, I already tried using **import()** but I can't get a working code as **import()** is non-blocking and won't fit with **export** (I got `function update() is undefined` [I think the module is not fully loaded])

Comment: In that first link `require()` is allowed right in your TypeScript.  I've never done that myself, but that's what the article implies.  You can NEVER export something retrieved from a dynamic import with `import()`.  ESM modules just don't work that way.  Exports have to be static.